# lstlisting with SuperCollider language - cannot use underscore character

Tags: underscore, lstlisting

The following fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{sclang-prettifier}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=SuperCollider-IDE]
current = x[0].collect(_.asArray);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> Improper alphabetic constant.

This is with Texlive 2016 and texlive-science installed for sclang-prettifier, but I suspect it's a general problem with lstlistings.

If I prefix with backslash:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{sclang-prettifier}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=SuperCollider-IDE]
current = x[0].collect(\_.asArray);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

That backslash is printed which is not desired:

[image]

Comment: check the answer to that question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303195/determine-if-inside-lstinline-or-ordinary-lstlisting-environment/303199#303199

Comment: @naphaneal thank you, that worked, although looks a bit clunky to address the issue.